# Is there any BulkUpdate Command similar to BulkCopy in SQL Server 2008

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-update, sqlbulkcopy

I have used `BulkCopy` command to transfer rows from one table to another table with bulk data about 3 to 5 million rows. I want to update these rows.

Is there any `BulkUpdate` command similar to the `BulkCopy` command? I'm using ASP.NET with C#.

Comment: It's the T-SQL `UPDATE` command .... just do your update operations on a set-based approach (not row-by-row), and do them on the SQL Server - don't pull down the whole data, update it, and send it back.

Answer (score 4):

No, there isn't.

Q: What's an "lac"?

This *might* help:

> http://itknowledgeexchange.techtarget.com/itanswers/bulk-update-in-sql-server-2005/
>
> Assuming that you have a column with distict values to show you which
>   rows are which between the two tables this can be done with a simple
>   update statement.

```
UPDATE TableA
SET TableA.A1 = TableB.B1,
    TableA.A2 = TableB.B2  
FROM TableB  
WHERE TableA.A3 = TableB.B3
```

> If you are worried about creating one massive transaction you can
>   batch the operation into smaller chunks. This is done via the TOP
>   keyword.

```
UPDATE TOP (1000) TableA
SET TableA.A1 = TableB.B1,
    TableA.A2 = TableB.B2  
FROM TableB  
WHERE TableA.A3 = TableB.B3
      AND TableA.A1 <> TableB.B1
      AND TableA.A2 <> TableB.B2
```

> You can put that into a loop...

Here's another link (with basically the same solution):

http://www.sqlusa.com/bestpractices2005/hugeupdate/

Answer (score 2):

A common approach here is:

- bulk-load (SqlBulkCopy) into an empty *staging table - meaning: a table with the right columns/types as the actual data, but not part of the main transactional system
- now do an update joining the real data to the staging data, to update the values in the real data

Answer (score -1):

**Disclaimer**: I'm the owner of the project [Bulk Operations](http://bulk-operations.net/)

The Bulk Operations Library allow to Insert, Delete, Update and Merge millions of rows in few seconds.

It's very easy to learn and use if you already know the SqlBulkCopy class.

```
var bulk = new BulkOperation(connection);
// ... Mappings ....

bulk.BulkUpdate(dt);
```